# Detect element deletion using MutationObserver

Tags: javascript, html, dom, mutation-observers

I want to observe and element that sometimes gets deleted and then recreated. My problem is that the observer gets destroyed with the element and doesn't get recreated with the element, and I have no way to detect when that happens in order to re-create the observer.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) says that "Note: According to specification a MutationObserver is deleted by the garbage collector if the target element is deleted."

Is there anyway to detect that deletion? I'm observing an element, I want to know when that element was deleted. I can detect if its sub-nodes have been deleted, but I have no way to detect if it itself has been removed.

I registered to all mutations but the callback doesn't get called when the element is deleted.

I tried setInterval to check every second if the element disappears but this doesn't work well when the element gets removed and then re-created quickly.

Comment: why can't you put that observer 1 level higher in the dom, to track that one continuously recreated element also?

Comment: Because it also gets deleted. It's an entire tree that gets deleted and then recreated. I can observe the entire document but I fear this will create lags

Comment: MutationObserver is very fast. As with most things in JS, unless you've actually measured and are seeing it cause lag, I'd say don't worry about it.

Comment: Well thanks for that idea. I'll try to mess around with it tomorrow. Just wish there was a better cleaner way. Really seems like a silly limitation of observers - you observe an element but can't really observe it's deletion. It's like I'm missing something here

Comment: When you observe an element you're explicitly observing that element. Then you remove an item, it is the item's parent node's child list that is being modified, not the item that was removed.

Comment: You'd still expect an Observer to detect that what it is observing has disappeared. And it actually does, because it stops observing, but the interface is limited and doesn't let me handle that.

Comment: You wouldn't expect observer to do anything except what's described in the specification. You can use a synchronous DOM mutation event in this case.

Comment: What does synchronous DOM mutation event mean? Could you provide me some link so I can read about it? Thanks

Comment: @Omer I guess what wOxxOm meant are [mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events), specifically `DOMNodeRemoved` and `DOMNodeRemovedFromDocument`. While those may work, they are deprecated and therefore not recommended to be used.

Answer (score 8):

A MutationObserver doesn't fire when the element on which it is set is removed. The [specification](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dictdef-mutationobserverinit) only allows to listen for changes on attributes, character data and child nodes.

So the solution to this is to set the MutationObserver on the parent (or ancestor) element that is not deleted. In the callback you then have to loop through the [MutationRecords](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationRecord) to check whether their `removedNodes` property contains the element you are looking for.

The code for that will look something like this:

```
let mutationObserver = new MutationObserver((mutationList, observer) => {
  for (let mutationRecord of mutationList) {
    if (mutationRecord.removedNodes) {
      for (let removedNode of mutationRecord.removedNodes) {
        if (removedNode.id === 'myElement') {
          ...
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The `return` statement is in there to stop looping through the rest of the elements once you handled the deletion of the searched element.